# An error about haskell composition

Tags: haskell, composition

I wrote a function:

```
inita xs = reverse . (drop 1) (reverse xs)
```

I thought it equals:

```
inita xs = reverse (  (drop 1) (reverse xs)  )
```

But I had errors:

```
 Couldn't match expected type ‘a -> [a1]’ with actual type ‘[a2]’
    Relevant bindings include
      xs :: [a2] (bound at ch2.hs:1:7)
      init1 :: [a2] -> a -> [a1] (bound at ch2.hs:1:1)
    Possible cause: ‘drop’ is applied to too many arguments
    In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘(drop 1) (reverse xs)’
    In the expression: reverse . (drop 1) (reverse xs)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

So what's wrong with that composition expression?

Comment: It is a reverse tail like init. inita = (reverse . tail . reverse)    -- parameters are superflous in eta converted expressions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`reverse ( (drop 1) (reverse xs) )` is equal to `(reverse . drop 1) (reverse xs)`. But that's not what `reverse . (drop 1) (reverse xs)` is parsed as, because infix operators have lower precedence than function application. For this reason, what it's actually parsed as is instead `reverse . ((drop 1) (reverse xs))`, but that doesn't make any sense (i.e. doesn't typecheck), because `(drop 1) (reverse xs)` is not a function but a list.

The preferred way to write such a function is

```
inita xs = reverse . drop 1 $ reverse xs
```

Here, I've replaced the high-precedence plain function application with the low-precedence `$` operator (which does nothing else but apply a function, but due to the low precedence it's actually this right composition-function).

Actually though, you don't need that, because you only pass in `xs` once at the end. So you might as well make `reverse` part of the composition chain too:

```
inita xs = reverse . drop 1 . reverse $ xs
```

...which can simply be η-reduced to

```
inita = reverse . drop 1 . reverse
```

Answer (score 3):

No, operators have a lower precedence than functions, so that means that your expression:

```
inita xs =  reverse  .  (drop 1) (reverse xs)
```

Is equal to:

```
inita xs = (reverse) . ((drop 1) (reverse xs))
```

or in a more canonical form:

```
inita xs = (.) (reverse) ((drop 1) (reverse xs))
```

Now `(.)` is defined as:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
(.) f g x = f (g x)
```

So in this context, `f = reverse`, and `g = ((drop 1) (reverse xs))`, so we have basically written:

```
inita xs = \x -> reverse ((drop 1) (reverse xs) x)
```

or we can move the `x` parameter to the head of the function:

```
inita xs x = reverse ((drop 1) (reverse xs) x)
```

So you are missing the `x` here in your rewrite. We can rewrite the code to:

```
inita = (reverse .) . drop 1 . reverse
```

since:

```
   inita xs = (.) reverse ((drop 1) (reverse xs))
-> inita xs = ((.) reverse) ((drop 1) (reverse xs))
-> inita xs = ((.) reverse) ((.) (drop 1) reverse xs)
-> inita = ((.) reverse) . ((.) (drop 1) reverse)
-> inita = ((.) reverse) . (drop 1 . reverse)
-> inita = ((.) reverse) . drop 1 . reverse
-> inita = (reverse .) . (drop 1 . reverse)
```